# Selenide: missing @Step annotation in Allure report

Tags: java, selenium, allure, selenide

i have following problem:

this is my repo: https://github.com/mtpx/N

In pages classes i use @Step annotation, after test execution in Allure report we see: [image]

I want to see my @Steps instead of: 
     $(By.xpath: //div[@id='messages_container']//span[@class='ui-growl-title'][0]) get text()

Do You know how to do it?
I tried solution from https://automated-testing.info/t/pomogite-razobratsya-s-otobrazheniem-step-v-allure-otchete/12045/5, i changed my pom.xml to

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>nawa</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.9.4</aspectj.version>

            <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-beta4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
     </dependency>
      <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>-->
             <dependency>
                      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                      <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
                      <version>1.5.4</version>
                  </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-beta4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
         <build>
             <plugins>
                 <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                     <version>3.6.1</version>
                     <configuration>
                         <source>1.8</source>
                         <target>1.8</target>
                     </configuration>
                 </plugin>
                 <plugin>
                     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                     <version>2.20</version>
                     <configuration>
                         <argLine>
                             -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                         </argLine>
                     </configuration>
                     <dependencies>
                         <dependency>
                             <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                             <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                             <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                         </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
                 </plugin>
             </plugins>
         </build>

     </project>
```

but now i cant compile my project, logs:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test
>   (default-test) on project nawa: There are test failures. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] Please refer to
>   C:\Users\mkrasny\IdeaProjects\nawa\target\surefire-reports for the
>   individual test results. [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any
>   exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and
>   [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream. [ERROR] There was an error in the forked
>   process [ERROR] javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator [ERROR]
>   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
>   was an error in the forked process [ERROR]
>   javax/xml/bind/ValidationEventLocator [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:665)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:279)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:243)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1077)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:907)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:785)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305) [ERROR]
>   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) [ERROR]
>   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956) [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [ERROR] at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192) [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   [ERROR] at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   [ERROR] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
>   [ERROR] at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full stack
>   trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. [ERROR] Re-run
>   Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `allure-selenide` dependency from your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
    <artifactId>allure-selenide</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ok, works, i have my steps in allure report, but now i dont have failure screenshot in allure (after allure-selenide dependency delete I had to remove lines `SelenideLogger.addListener("AllureSelenide", new AllureSelenide().screenshots(true).savePageSource(true));` and `SelenideLogger.removeListener("allureSelenide");` from @BeforeClass and @AfterClass )

Comment: maybe anserw is here https://www.swtestacademy.com/allure-testng/, I'll check it later

Answer (score 0):

To be able have step and open in as parent block ( like this in green color ➡️) you need to add begin you method with: `SelenideLog logSelenide = SelenideLogger.beginStep("<TEXT>", "<STRING>");`
And when you finish you method close the block with `SelenideLogger.commitStep(logSelenide, LogEvent.EventStatus.PASS);`

- If you call another method with the same block of SelenideLogger, this will be blocked in a partnership.

Cheers